# X3:TC - Unlock all Starts

Tags: macos, x3-terran-conflict

I'm currently playing through X3 : Terran Conflict, and am wondering how I would be able to unlock all the starts, without having to unlock them manually.

I'm on a Mac, running the latest version of El Capitan. I have found numerous ways to do this on Linux, and Windows with `regedit`, but OS X doesn't have an equivalent.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Whoever cast that close vote: We do help with cheating in single player games as long as it is only for your own benefit. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/where-do-we-stand-on-cheating-in-single-player-games Therefore it is not offtopic.

Comment: @BulliedByMods Always good to know. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems the only way to do this is to load up a save that has met all requirements. Return to main menu and bonus game starts should be available.

Comment: Note: I had trouble where I actually had to load the save where I had to complete an action to unlock the ability to get the game starts. e.g. I couldnt already be level 12, I had to load my save which was just before I got the requirements to get to level 12.